# Formatting build.gradle automatically

Tags: groovy, gradle

Does a nice API exist to format gradle files with specific configuration (tabs, indentation,...) ?
I had a look over `org.hibernate.tools` java formatter, but there is no mean to handle files except java sources.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a tool that can handle Groovy sources, such as IntelliJ or Eclipse (with Groovy plugin). I'm not aware of a command line tool or API for formatting Groovy sources, but perhaps a web search will turn up something.

Comment: there is an attempt with [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net) project. But it seems not very efficient for handling gradle build files which have most of the time a lot of declarative dependencies.